# termite instead of letters displays squares (arch-linux)

Tags: arch-linux, termite

After today system update(linux-5.2.3.arch1-1, linux-headers-5.2.3.arch1-1) my terminal(termite) started display squares instead of letters.
I am using xos4 Terminus font. It installed and on previous system version it worked normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

The upgrade to pango 1.44 removed support for bitmap fonts.

Here is the relevant issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango/issues/386

Downgrading pango to 1.43 fixed the problem for me (though I don't believe that solution will work forever).

Comment: Thx for your response. I am already fix this while browsing through updated packages.